# Insert rows from $_POST when inputs are arrays with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I have a dynamic form generated by a while loop that looks like this:

```
<form>
<?php while ($questions = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
<textarea name="reponse_text[]"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="question_id[]" value="<?php echo $questions['question_id']; ?>">
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

I am trying to insert each 'response' and 'question_id' into its own row. I believe using a forloop to do this is necessary but can't figure out how to access each POST array value:

```
$user_checkup_id = $db->lastInsertId();

$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_responses (user_response_text, question_id, user_checkup_id) 
VALUES (:user_response_text, :question_id, :user_checkup_id)");

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

    $query->bindValue(':user_checkup_id', $user_checkup_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    if($key == "response_text") {
        $query->bindValue(':response_text', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    } else if($key == "question_id") {
        $query->bindValue(':question_id', $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
}

$query->execute();
```

The value submitting to the database is "Array" for response_text. How do I access the actually text area value for each row?

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` will show you the structure of the data you have to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST['reponse_text']` is an array, access it like one. The match number of token error is because you have an if/else condition on one of the parameter being defined.

```
foreach ($_POST['reponse_text'] as $i => $value) {

    $query->bindValue(':user_checkup_id', $user_checkup_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $query->bindValue(':response_text', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':question_id', $_POST['question_id'][$i], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    // here you do them at once or the other parameter won't be defined

    $query->execute(); // then you execute, for each different response text
}
```

be sure to put the `execute()` *in* the foreach or it will get executed after the whole thing, effectively only inserting the last response text having been bound to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($_POST["reponse_text"] as $key => $value) {

    $query->bindValue(':user_checkup_id', $user_checkup_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    if($key == "response_text") {
        $query->bindValue(':response_text', $_POST['reponse_text'][$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    } else if($key == "question_id") {
        $query->bindValue(':question_id', $_POST['question_id'][$key], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this and get the error: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens